# How do I unset a region in template.php AND have it alter the body classes

Tags: theming

In some cases I need to programmatically remove the sidebar_first region in template.php.  So, I'm doing something like:

```
function template_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if(my_condition){
    unset($variables['page']['sidebar_first']);
  }
}
```

this does, indeed, remove the sidebar, however, it does NOT alter the body classes.  So, I still have a class of

```
body.two-sidebars
```

...even though I unset one of them (so the proper class would be body.one-sidebar).

How can I programmatically remove a sidebar AND have it alter the body classes properly?

(please, for various reasons dont suggest creating a new template suggestion and altering the sidebar there.  that won't work in my case.  I am asking specifically how to remove a region programmatically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I basically figured out that the problem is that you have to do this in two different template.php functions:  template_preprocess_page (to kill the sidebar) AND template_preprocess_html (to get rid of the body class I didn't want).

so first in preprocess_page:

```
$variables['page']['sidebar_first'] = NULL;
```

then in preprocess_html I had to get node info with menu_get_object(), check the node data for my condition, then parse the $variables['classes_array'] to manually replace the 'two-sidebars' class and add anything else I want.

*Sheesh.  Should be much easier, but I thank the guys in the other answers for helping me confirm it's not as simple as it should be.*

Comment: I'm glad you figured out your problem.  Most themeing tasks do usually boil down to messing around with the `$variables` array in a preprocess function.  Drupal 7 split out html from page, which helps in some places, but does complicate others.  That said, my advice or @greg_1_anderson's should have worked.  Something doesn't seem quite right with the symptoms you described.

Comment: Just noted: A side-effect of removing the sidebar(s) from the page as you describe is for the correct `no-sidebars` or `has-one-sidebar` whatever classes to be set on the `<body>`. So if you have no other requirements for the body classes, you need not bother parsing / updating  `$variables['classes_array']`.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the default [`template_preprocess_html`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/7), you will see

```
  // Add information about the number of sidebars.
  if (!empty($variables['page']['sidebar_first']) && !empty($variables['page']['sidebar_second'])) {
    $variables['classes_array'][] = 'two-sidebars';
  }
  elseif (!empty($variables['page']['sidebar_first'])) {
    $variables['classes_array'][] = 'one-sidebar sidebar-first';
  }
  elseif (!empty($variables['page']['sidebar_second'])) {
    $variables['classes_array'][] = 'one-sidebar sidebar-second';
  }
  else {
    $variables['classes_array'][] = 'no-sidebars';
  }
```

If you don't want this behavior, you should implement your own version which will run after.  Then, you just check your condition and muck with `$variables['classes_array']` as needed.

Comment: But, I can't detect if I should unset it here because my condition that I'm checking is in $node...and $node isn't an available variable in preprocess_html

Comment: If template_process_page is no good, then you can certainly remove the class in template_process_html.  You should be able to find some hook that runs before template_process_html (e.g. template_preprocess_page) that has access to $node; you could set a flag at in that function, and act on it in template_process_html.

Comment: if I could get that "flag" in preprocess_html that's probably what I need.  How would I set that in page and pass it to html?

Comment: Isn't $variables['page']['sidebar_first'] unset in preprocess_html if you've already altered it in preprocess_page?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to find the information you need in `$variabless['classes_array']`, which contains an array of body classes.  Just remove the one whose value is two-sidebars.

Comment: Yup, thats what I thought too.  But the classes array is empty.

Comment: Try removing it in template_process_page instead of template_preprocess_page.

Comment: in both preprocess and process my classes_array only contains one item, which is  0 => page